# Encryption of data between clients and firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering is there any encryption mechanism that protects the data transferred between the real time data base of firebase and the users, to avoid potential Men In the Middle attack ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All traffic between the Firebase Database servers and your Android app goes over encrypted connections. You can easily see this when you look at the URL that is used to connect to your database: `https://<project-name>.firebaseio.com`.